# heat map hide columns by date

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

Iv set up a custom onClick event to hide columns in a heat map using a "fake group". Everything works, as long as you wait till the animations finish before clicking on another year form the yearSlicer. Clicking before it is finished loading will cause unwanted results.

fake group:

```
 function filter_bins(source_group, f) {
     return {
         all: function () {
             return source_group.all().filter(function (d) {
                 return f(d.value);
             });
        }
     };
  }

  var filtered_years_group = filter_bins(FTEMonthGroup, function (d) {
      return yearsHidden.length == 0 ? !yearsHidden.includes(d.Year) : yearsHidden.includes(d.Year);
  });
```

yearSlicer onClick:

```
   yearSlicer.on("renderlet.somename", function (chart) {
        chart.selectAll('rect').on("click", function (d) {
            hideYear(d.key);
            return chart._onClick(d)
        });
    });
```

setting years to hide:

```
var yearsHidden = [];
var hideYear = function (year) {
    var index = yearsHidden.indexOf(year);
    if (index === -1) {
        yearsHidden.push(year);
    } else {
         yearsHidden.splice(index, 1);
    }
    heatMap.redraw();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/_M_M_/fLvugo3h/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I observed that sometimes the heatmap data would not be filtered by the current selection of years, causing grey cells to appear. Hope this is the same problem you are describing!

I'm not sure what is going wrong here, but I noticed that yearsHidden is the same as `yearSlicer.filters()` - you are duplicating the toggle behavior that the chart already has.

It's always nice to fix a bug by deleting code. I found that I could fix it by changing the `filter_bins` function to

```
var filtered_years_group = filter_bins(FTEMonthGroup, function(d) {
  var years = yearSlicer.filters();
  return years.length ? years.includes(d.Year) : true;
});
```

and then remove everything to do with `yearsHidden`, as well as the click event handler.

https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/8npv5zhq/19/

Without going into a deep debugging session, my guess is that they got out of synch because a lot of the click handlers for dc.js are asynchronous. So your handler could get called at different times from the dc.js filtering code.